# Need Help For MVC Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, entity

I have two Tables in my database one contains User List And Their information.
and 2nd contains the data submitted by them.
(every user can submit their own data)

but these users are under Any User
like this :
user15  works under  User-Manager
user16 works under User-Manager
user_xyz works under User-Manager2

├── manager 1/ 
│   ├── User 15 
│   ├── User 16

|── Manager 2/ 
    ├── User xyz 
    ├── User Pqr

i want to get all the data from data table of all user who are working under Manager-1
 but i am able to do that.

i am doing this to get the list of Users

```
var t = db.Users.Where(u => u.Under_Control ==  Manager-1).Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
```

it gives me the list of users who are working under Manager-1 Or Manager-2

then i am trying to retrieve  data from Data table by using loop
eg

```
foreach(var item in db.userdata) {
    create new list of all data... 
    }
```

i am failed then i tried this way

```
var test = (from usr in db.Users from data in db.userdata where user.Under_Control==Undr select data).ToList():
```

but i am not able to do this.

> I Simple Words
>   *I have two tables One With Data and Another with Users*
>   Each User Works under Their Own Manager

Now what i want the data from Data Table which is submitted by all users who are working under Manager-1
that means if Manager-1 have five user show all data of these five users only, to Manager-1;

thanks Hope you understand my problem.

Here is My Table 1: 
Username  some-more-info   Under_Control 
user-15   more info of usr  Manager-1 
user-16   more info of usr  Manager-1 
user-xyz   more info of usr  Manager-2

Table 2: 
Submitted_by  Date     More Fields 
user-15       10/01    
user-15       10/01

how i can get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join - You can try this.

```
 var result = (from u in users
             join d in data on u.user equals d.user
    where users.under_Control == "Manager-1"
             select new{  something = d.something}).ToList();
```

you may have to update this query.